# How do I get detailed Gradle profile data?

Tags: gradle, build, profile, drilldown

I am using the `--profile` flag on my Gradle build to see how much time each task uses, but it doesn't provide fine-grained data.

I'd like to drill further down, to see how much time each test takes.  I need this to identify which tests consume the most time, by sorting by time elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

The test result report at `build/reports/test/index.html` should already provide you the information you are seeking.

Comment: Is it possible to create an aggregated report as json, xml or csv?  I'd like to sort the data by time elapsed.

Comment: Well, you can find the JUnit Ant task compatible XML version in `build/test-results/test/` and aggregate from there yourself. Alternatively I think you could also implement an own ReportGenerator that produces a report to your liking.